# Determining if two statements are equivalent, logical sense.

Tags: logic, proof-writing, induction

I am confused, I am working with proofs and I have the following statement to work with

$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},P(n) \implies P(n+1)$

1. I have a second statement
   $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, P(n)\Rightarrow \forall n\in\mathbb{N},P(n+1)$

I thought they were equivalent, but now I am confused because I am asked to use parenthesis to express the second statement in a much 'closer' way to the first statement... which imo means that I am looking at two logically distinct statements, but why?

And also, 2. is there any way I can rewrite $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},P(n+1)$ without addition?

I have 6 proofs to work with that relay on this main question I am asking; therefore, I need your help trying to understand this...

Can someone place some explanation in natural language of why they aren't equivalent, I was reading them like this:

If theres an $n, P(n)$, and the second one, if theres an $n$ then $P(n)$ then there is an $n (p + 1)$ but sounds too awkward and I don't get what I'm saying.

Comment: Statement 1 is confusing because it seems to have two different variables that are both named $n$. The “$n$” in $P(n+1)$ might be the same as the $n$ in $P(n)$, or not. In the first case you are saying $$\def\a{\forall}\def\ia{\implies\a}\def\m#1{\color{maroon}{#1}}\def\ii{\in\Bbb N}\a n\ii. P(n)\ia m\ii. P(\m n+1);$$ in the second you are saying $$\a n\ii. P(n)\ia m\ii. P(\m m+1).$$ These are quite different statements, and without explanation there is no way to know which one is meant. I *guess* the second one is what is meant, and I suggest you write it that way, without using $n$ twice.

Comment: The first one is basically the base structure for an inductive proof (if P(0) and S1 then for all n P(n)... however, we are still working on the theoretical part of this topic so I need to understand why S1 is diff from S2, where does that m come from in the first statement you posted?

Comment: I believe the last sentence of the question has something wrong about it, so please check if that is what you are really trying to say (I don't understand what it is supposed to mean).

Comment: As for MJD's answer, in the second statement of the question (which is confusingly labeled 1.), $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ appears twice, which can be confusing (it is 'different' n each time, if the concept of difference makes any sense when talking about all elements of a set at once, but it is a different placeholder letter), so he just replaced one of those ns with an m, for clarity's sake. However, it is not clear which of the two ns is the one at the end, thus MJD's confusion. My money is on the second case.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the correct reading of :

> $\forall n \in \mathbb N,P(n) \rightarrow P(n+1)$

must be :

> $\forall n (P(n) \rightarrow P(n+1))$ --- **(*)**

omitting the specification "$\in \mathbb N$", for simplicity.

As said above, it is the standard expression of the *inductive step* of an *inductive proof* (where $P(0)$ is the *basis step*).

The formula :

> $\forall n P(n) \rightarrow \forall n P(n+1)$

is equivalent to :

> $\forall n P(n) \rightarrow \forall n (n > 0 \rightarrow P(n))$ ---**(§)**.

The two formulae are **not** equivalent.

Consider as $P(x)$ the predicate : $(x=0)$.

With this interpretation, from **(*)** we have :

> $\forall n(n=0 \rightarrow n+1=0)$

which is false, because for $n=0$ we have that $(n=0 \rightarrow n+1=0)$ is *false* [$0=0$ is true, while $0+1 = 0$ is false; then apply truth-table for $\rightarrow$]. Thus, it is not true that $(n=0 \rightarrow n+1=0)$ is true for all $n$.

On the other hand, from **(§)** we have :

> $\forall n(n=0) \rightarrow \forall n (n > 0 \rightarrow n=0)$

which is trivially *true*, because $\forall n(n=0)$ is *false*.